# How to understand "on which to be" in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> He lay in a bright mist, though it was not like mist he had ever experienced before. His surroundings were not hidden by cloudy vapour; rather the cloudy vapour had not yet formed into surroundings. The floor on which he lay seemed to be white, neither warm nor cold, but simply there, a flat, blank something **on which to be**.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sub>

How should we understand "on which to be" here? I just can't figure it out.

Comment: *With just a thin mattress on which to lie, and a small chair on which to sit, his prison cell was bare and uninviting. It really was a depressing place in which to be.* Stylised alternatives to *a thin mattress **to lie on**, a small chair **to sit on**, a depressing place **to be in***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He is conscious of being supported by some kind of surface, but the surroundings are so vague that he can't say for certain that he is lying on a floor - it's just *something he is on.*

Answer (score 0):

Just my opinion.. I think the meaning will not change too much if change end of the sentence from "on which to be" to "on which he has to be now". I think this meaning the same in main.

Comment: I'm thinking: *something to be on (which)* -> *something on which to be*. Is it how it works?

Comment: Yes, I think you're right, something like this.

Comment: _...on which he have to be now_ doesn't have a clear meaning either (anyway, it's _he has to be_).

Comment: Yes, my mistake! Thank you!